# Saturn's tropical year

Tags: planet

What is the value of Saturn's "tropical year" (as opposed to its "sidereal year").

I am seeing it listed as 10 days shorter (10,747 days) than the sidereal year (10,759 days).
How could this be if the precession of the axis is so slow (1.86M years)?
Is this an "transient" value?
Am I completely missing something?

see also: [NASA planetary facts data on Saturn](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/saturnfact.html)

Comment: Welcome to the site, however this more properly belongs on [Astronomy.se].

Comment: now reposting (crossposting?) on astronomy...  and deleted again :-) (see comment below)

Comment: Oh, no need - it will be moved if it is agreed the better fit is on Astronomy. And in the meantime, you may well get an answer here, we certainly have people who might be able to answer. Actually, crossposting is against policy, instead things are migrated. The moderators will move the question if it is closed, no worries.

Comment: @kimholder if someone want's to delete their post and copy/paste it somewhere else, that's a quick solution and doesn't make any work for anyone else. Putting the question here in a twilight zone of a few close votes, and waiting for "agreement" and then a moderator to migrate seems like a waste of several peoples time as well as delaying the OP from getting an answer.

Comment: @PaulS you're already a member of Astronomy SE. I'd say just copy/paste to a question there and then delete here. It's the quickest solution. Looking forward to seeing the answer! Fyi this says the period of spin-axis precession is only 260,000 years; https://www.quora.com/How-fast-is-the-precession-of-Jupiters-spin-axis Oh this says 180,000 years; https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/the-perihelion-precession-of-jupiter.477720/

Comment: @uhoh Fair point.

Comment: Now moved to [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/)  forum: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26594/saturns-tropical-year.  Ambiguity was because it involves orbital mechanics.

Comment: Uhoh's comment is quite fair, another path is that you could delete this here and post it there, and thus not have to wait. Up to you.

Comment: @PaulS ya there are cases where a question can be on-topic in both sites at the same time, and "more on topic somewhere else" is not a close reason by itself, nor does it mean off-topic here. How to decide to post in Astronomy vs Space is a challenge sometimes. Now that you've posted elsewhere, and if this question isn't closed, you should consider deleting it at some point.